# How to gradually rotate a user control?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am trying to gradually rotate a user control by adjusting the Angle of a RotateTransform gradually over a period of time. I imagine I will have to use threading, but I am not quite sure what the general approach should be.

I want it to be something like: 
every 10 seconds, increase the angle of the RotateTransform by some small increment

Thanks for reading

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69048/Tutorial-Creating-a-Lookless-WPF-Custom-Rotate-Con

Comment: I would expect you should be able to apply an animation to the transform property. What have you tried? What happened? How was that different from what you wanted? Where is your code? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Storyboard with Double Animation to do this,

```
     <Storyboard x:Key="myStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="myUserControl"
                         From="0"
                         To="360"
                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                         Duration="0:0:0.3">

        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```